# Invalid template argument in constructor parameter list

Tags: c++

Good evening, I am trying to make a templated class which will have two members that are const_iterators point to the beginning and end of a subsection of a vector. I wanted to make the class generic so that I can use it for a vector of any type.

My class definitions is in file ThreadWorker.h and looks as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class VectorWorker
{
public:
    VectorWorker<T>() = default;
    VectorWorker<T>( std::vector<typename T>::const_iterator begin,  std::vector<typename T>::const_iterator end);
    void Work() const;

private:
    std::vector<typename T>::const_iterator beginIt; /* Stores value of left iterator that defines data for this worker */
    std::vector<typename T>::const_iterator endIt; /* Stores value of right iterator that defines data for this worker */
};
```

When i attempt to compile my code I get an error stating that the template arguments are invalid:

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
     VectorWorker<T>( std::vector<typename T>::const_iterator begin,  std::vector<typename T>::const_iterator end);
```

I don't quite understand why I am getting this error, since I have specified via the "typename" keyword that T is a typename template parameter. Could anyone help explain what is going on here, or point me to a good resource? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator` (pretty much everywhere in this code, btw). An excellent  Q+A about both `typename` and `template` usage [can be found on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: Ok that looks like it solved the error. Although, I do not understand why.

Comment: That was the reason for the followup link I provided, which discusses in detail where and how to use `typename`. Click the link in the last sentence ([or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords())).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `typename` outside of the `template` argument list:

```
template<typename T>
class VectorWorker {
private:
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator beginIt;
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator endIt;
public:
    VectorWorker<T>() = default;
    VectorWorker<T>( typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin, typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator end ) :
        beginIt( begin ),
        endIt( end ) 
    {}    
};
```

What you previously had as both members and Constructor Parameters

> ```
> std::vector<typename T>::const_iterator beginIt; 
> std::vector<typename T>::const_iterator endIt;
>
> std::vector<typename T>::const_iterator begin;
> std::vector<typename T>::const_iterator end;
> ```

Are not `Types`

To resolve this the template parameter list for the members as well as the constructor parameters only needs the template type `<T>`

To make the `const_iterator`s a type you need to declare them as a `typename`

```
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator name;
```

Comment: Yeah that fixes it. So does placing the typename keyword before the templated formal parameter of the function let the compiler know that the following syntax represents a type?

Comment: @FilipGajowniczek Correct.

Comment: @FilipGajowniczek as super has said; yes.